# WordPress - получить мета поля постов и сложить их

Tags: php, wordpress

Что имеем: несколько записей типа post с произвольным полем `meta_key`.
Как с помощью стандартного запроса `WP_Query` получить все `meta_key` постов и сложить их?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант если подойдет через $wpdb->get_var

```
<?php $amount = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT sum(meta_value)  FROM $wpdb->postmeta  WHERE meta_key = %s ", 'слаг_произвольного_поля' ) ); echo "Сумма равна {$amount}"; ?>
```

Comment: Да, подойдет. Возможно ли модифицировать такую выборку на пример за год? И месяц?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение:

```
$summ_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post'
);
$query= new WP_Query( $summ_args );
$posts = $query->posts;

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $summ += get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_key', true);

}
echo $summ;
wp_reset_postdata();
```